# Are any 5e multiclassing options particularly strong compared to the base classes?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

In D&D 3.5e, in my experience, multiclassing was a very common choice, and the prestige class system, where you're basically always going off of the base classes at high level anyway made taking a few levels of another base class seem like a relatively normal option — at every level, you're choosing which class to advance in, and hey, why not add a level of rogue? (Assuming *favored class* matched up and all that.)

Overall, I think it's generally the case that multiclassing was awful for spellcasters, but pretty nifty for martial characters — no real downsides, and a lot of customization. Ranger/Rogue split for the first 10 levels or so makes a nice "scout" time of character — arguably better than the "Scout" base class published later. In many ways, this felt like it meant that a dozen base classes equaled a thousand class possibilities (even if most of those were poor).

In making a D&D 5e character (starting at level 3 for a one-off play session), I was trying to look for interesting combinations, and kind of coming up blank. 5e softens the spellcaster problem (with shared "caster levels" and slots when you multiclass) and removes the alignment restrictions and favored classes in favor of (fairly low) ability prereqs. But, on the other side, 1) multiclassing now only grants a limited number of proficiencies for additional classes, and 2) there are increasingly-better class abilities as you go up, and 3) ability score boosts and feats are now tied to *class levels* — multiclassing means delaying (and forgoing) these.

So: ***are* there 5e classes which *do* synergize nicely for multiclassing?** Or do these all trade shiny, shiny versatility for being distinctly behind the curve? **Is multiclassing a trap?** (Still a thousand options, but now *all* of them poor?) Note that I'm *not* looking at loss of 20th-level capstone abilities, but low- and mid-level play (level 3 in the example at hand, but let's say also 5th and 10th.)

Comment: I think this is too broad to be a good question for the site; it's basically an invitation to a never-ending discussion about "well THIS combo is good" "well no it's not..." With also being largely opinion-based. I'm not sure what a good answer looks like.

Comment: I don't think that's true; I think the question can be reasonably answered for 3.5 (which is why I started with that), and I don't see why this edition is different in answerability, even if the answer is different. (In, fact, "This can't be determined in this edition, because _reasons_" might be a good answer, if that were the case.)

Comment: There are something like 11^20 - 11 different multiclass combinations. Proving that multiclassing is a bad choice would require proving that none of these are a good idea.

Comment: @Miniman Yes, but to answer the question, you only need to demonstrate that at least some of them are fine. (Or more ideally, that _sets of combinations_ are fine — as in the example of 3.5E, where martial classes generally multiclass well — and, as a the-way-the-rules-work thing, not as just opinion).

Comment: Your question boils down to "is multiclassing ever better than staying in one class". That's an opinion-based question that will produce subjective answers. Maybe change to "Can you give multiclassing examples that enable optimizations that aren't available to a single class".

Comment: Even with "prove one," I don't know what real play problem  you are trying to solve. "Winning an Internet fight" is not an interesting problem for purposes of this site.

Comment: I'm not having an Internet fight... I'm making a character for an upcoming game. As I said in the question. I mean, I see that this isn't a "look at page 237 and read paragraph 3..." question, but if it were there would be no need to ask for experienced advice.

Comment: And... I don't really want to have an Internet fight _here_ either. If everyone thinks the site isn't the right place, fine.

Comment: I think this could be a good question if you emphasized the “Is multiclassing a trap?” element. It could be the case that it’s a trap for some classes but not others (like spellcasters in D&D3). And it could be that some classes are especially well-suited to multiclassing or level drops.

Comment: @mattdm would the fact that you can gain proficiency in all 18 skills count as a good reason / not trap for multiclassing?

Comment: I think the question is in better QA format now.

Comment: @mattdm: Here's one example (unless it gets errataed)--dipping 1-2 levels of 'lock, with a Sorcerer, essentially nets you the capstone feature (since you can trade 'lock slots for Sorcery Points after each short rest). Also, 3 levels of 'lock can almost get you the Wizard capstone (2 L2 spells, as opposed to 2 L3). 

That's all I have.

Comment: @mattdm: Also, there might be something good with Assassins and Shadow Monks, but haven't looked at it in detail.

Comment: @Khashir I'm still looking at creating an optimised Assassin/Shadow Monk at the moment. Since I'm (relatively) new to the boards, what's the best way to discuss that - through chat? Asking a few broad questions hasn't gone too well for me haha.

Comment: @Tommy: Chat is the way to go, though I'm getting stumped by how to create a user-to-user chat--anyway, I looked over both classes, I think one optimised combination would be 3 Rogue (to get Assassin), 17 Shadow Monk. You give up an ability increase, but 2 levels of Rogue gives you Cunning Action, which is as good, if not better, than almost any feat (and it actually provides you an improved and free Step of the Wind). I wouldn't go 4/16 because you'd be stuck with a 1d8 Unarmed Strike.

Comment: @Tommy: I would pair that with Alert (to maximise Assassinate), and either Polearm Master or Sentinel (to have more opportunities to attack with your reaction, which lets you deal Sneak Attack damage outside your turn). Most people are fans of Polearm Master, but I think Sentinel would work better (since it allows either an Opportunity Attack or a Melee Weapon attack, if an enemy attacks an ally). Paired with Shadow Monk's L17 feature, you should be able to use your reaction almost every turn.

Comment: @Tommy: Just make sure your Dex and Wis are at 16 from L1. Furthermore, if you do take both feats, you won't be able to maximise Wis and your AC will suffer. So, if you can discuss with your GM whether Bracers of Defense will be available (+3 AC when wearing no armour or shield), then you'll be fine with the feats... if not, an AC of 18 will not be enough to survive mid-late game.

Comment: @Khashir Hmm... chat looks like it has to be public - let's try [continuing this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18395/discussion-between-khashir-and-tommy) though...